# inner product of mean convergent $L^2$ series of variables converges to inner product of limits

Tags: probability, expected-value

Assume that $X_n$ and $Y_n$ both in $L^2 = \{X \in \mathbb{R}; \mathbb{E}[X^2] < \infty \}$ converge to $X$ and $Y$ in mean square. Define $\langle X,Y \rangle = \mathbb{E}[XY]$. How do i show that $\lim_{n \to \infty}\langle X_n,Y_n \rangle=\langle X,Y \rangle$?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Most important is the estimate
$$|\langle X, Y \rangle| = |E(XY)| \leq \|X\|_{L^2}\|Y\|_{L^2},$$
known as Cauchy's inequality. In general a bilinear map $B : V \times W \to X$, where $U, V, X$ are normed vector spaces, is continuous if and only if there exists $C > 0$ such that $\|B(u, v)\| \leq C\|u\|\|v\|$ for all $u \in U, v \in V$. Proof is here: http://users.mat.unimi.it/users/libor/Real/bilinear.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
\begin{aligned}
|\mathbb{E}X_nY_n-\mathbb{E}XY| & = |\mathbb{E}X_nY_n-\mathbb{E}XY_n+\mathbb{E}XY_n-XY| \\
& =  |\mathbb{E}X_nY_n-\mathbb{E}XY_n|+|\mathbb{E}XY_n-XY| \\
& = |\mathbb{E}(X_n-X)Y_n|+|\mathbb{E}X(Y_n-Y)| \\
&\leqslant [\mathbb{E}(X_n-X)^2]^{1/2}(\mathbb{E}Y_n^2)^{1/2}+(\mathbb{E}X^2)^{1/2}[\mathbb{E}(Y_n-Y)^2]^{1/2}\\
&\to 0.
\end{aligned}.
$$
Thus, $\lim_n \mathbb{E}X_nY_n=\mathbb{E}XY$.

Comment: $\mathbb{E}[X_n Y_n] \rightarrow \mathbb{E}[XY]$ does not imply $X_n Y_n \rightarrow XY$ a.s.

Comment: @snar Yes. But this problem is not to prove $X_nY_n\to XY$ a.s., just $\mathbb{E}X_nY_n\to XY$.

Comment: @MHMH Not $\mathbb{E} X_nY_n \to  XY$ but $\mathbb{E} X_nY_n \to \mathbb{E} XY$. I have taken the liberty of correcting the last line.

Comment: @geetha290krm Agree. Thanks.